# Compare benchmarks of CodeIgniter vs Yii

Tags: php, codeigniter, yii, benchmarking

I am searching for the fastest framework in PHP.

I have found [one benchmark](http://www.yiiframework.com/performance) in which Yii is faster than CodeIgniter, and [another benchmark](http://doophp.com/benchmark) in which CodeIgniter is faster than Yii.

So, which is faster?

Comment: Benchmarks aren't accurate assessors of performance unless you are going to be performing exactly the task benchmarked in your code.

Comment: Faster to run or faster to develop in, or faster to extend/improve later?

Comment: Do we have to go through this debate again of which framework is faster?

Comment: based on Google trends Yii is on the top [google.com/trends...](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#cat=0-13&q=yii%2C%20%20codeigniter%2C%20%20cakephp%2C%20%20symfony%2C%20%20zend&cmpt=q)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your [first benchmark](http://www.yiiframework.com/performance/) : 
there is codeigniter 1.7.0 and Yii 1.0.2
After that codeigniter has many changes and in your [second benchmark](http://doophp.com/benchmark) :
there is codeigniter 2.0 and yii 1.1.6

So latest codeigniter 2.0 is better than yii according to this benchmarks.

Comment: Frameworks take side to their project. It's not sensible to just trust to these data.

Answer (score 4):

Although this does not directly apply to speed, we built an open source CRM application (Zurmo.org) using Yii. Before we started building Zurmo, we looked at Yii, Cakephp, Zend, and Codeigniter. We felt Yii was a great framework because it was lightweight, fast, and clean. It had a full set of functionality and matched up well with the other frameworks. We are delighted with the decision.

Answer (score 2):

As per the market stats, Codeigniter is one of the fastest growing framework. Yii is in the initial release of the frameworks.
Codeigniter has its own set of libraries whereas the Yii framework inherits the style from the three well known frameworks - Codeigniter, Symphony and Zend.
Both of them have a concept of Lazy loading i.e. resources are only loaded when required.
So it will be difficult to say which one is faster but they can be used as per the requirement of the product to be developed.

Comment: And it still is, Codeigniter is tsill growing see Google trends http://www.google.com/trends/explore#cat=0-13&q=codeigniter%2C%20yii%2C%20cakephp%2C%20symfony%2C%20zend&cmpt=q